# How to combine 2 rows into 1 row in pandas based on a column (obj)

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe info:

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A_mean          6 non-null float64
time_range      6 non-null object
time_range_1    6 non-null object
B               6 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(3)
```

Here is the `df`:

```
df

index    A_mean    time_range    time_range_1    B
0       5.936667       07       08:00 - 08:59   1001
1       5.103241       08       08:00 - 08:59   1001
2       5.267687       09       09:00 - 09:59   1001
```

I was trying to combine this two rows:

```
index    A_mean    time_range    time_range_1    B
0       5.936667       07       08:00 - 08:59   1001
1       5.103241       08       08:00 - 08:59   1001
```

Into one row, the desired output should be as below:

```
index    A_mean    time_range    time_range_1    B
0       5.519954       08       08:00 - 08:59   1001
```

** P/S: The most important columns will be the `A_mean` & `time_range_1` and column B should stay the same.

I've tried `.groupby`, but I've got the error:

```
df2 = df.groupby('time_range_1')['A_mean'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.float64 found
```

Any solution will be appreciated but in "pythonic" way (pandas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.groupby(['time_range_1', 'B'], as_index=False).agg({'A_mean': 'mean', 'time_range':'last'})
```

Result:

```
    time_range_1     B    A_mean  time_range
0  08:00 - 08:59  1001  5.519954           8
1  09:00 - 09:59  1001  5.267687           9
```

Comment: Thank you @liliscent for your quick respond! Oh ya, can use .agg! You have save my day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have try another way round to solve but not in 1 code:

```
df2= df.groupby(df.time_range_1).mean().reset_index()
df2['B'] = '1001'

Output:
index    time_range_1    A_mean      B
0       08:00 - 08:59   5.519954    1001
1       09:00 - 09:59   5.267687    1001
```